# Magento / Zend Framework : Custom Join Statement : ERROR : Can't prepare expression when tableName is instance of Zend_Db_Expr

Tags: mysql, magento, join, zend-framework

In Magento v1 I am trying to add a custom Inner Join as follows :

```
INNER JOIN (SELECT entity_id, LEFT(sku, 11) AS lwin11 FROM catalog_product_flat_1) AS test_lwin11 ON test_lwin11.entity_id = e.entity_id
```

I tries using 
    new Zend_Db_Expr

```
$select->joinInner(['test_lwin11' => new Zend_Db_Expr('(SELECT entity_id, LEFT(sku, 11) AS lwin11 FROM catalog_product_flat_1)')], 'test_lwin11.entity_id = e.entity_id');
```

but this is throwing the following Error :

Can't prepare expression when tableName is instance of Zend_Db_Expr

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
$connection = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
$tlw11 = $connection ->select()->from('catalog_product_flat_1', ['entity_id', 'lwin11' => 'LEFT(sku, 11)']);
```

Then

```
->join(['test_lwin11' => $tlw11], 'test_lwin11.entity_id = e.entity_id')
```